# How to make a request to get all information of a tenant like microsoft teams does?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I was reading the Microsoft Graph API Documentation to batch queries [right here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) and did not find what I need.
Basically I need to combine two or more requests but one depends to another value. I know there is a "dependsOn" feature to wait the other request, it is not what I am looking for.

Request one: GET '/me/joinedTeams';
Request two: GET 'teams/{groupId}/channels';

The "Request one" returns an array of groups and inside these array values there's an *id* property. Can I batch these two requests using the value of ther first one to get the second?

I am searching a way to do a GET and return all values of one teant like the Microsoft Teams Application does, returning all teams, all chats, etc. Batching requests is the more closer we can get it I think.
Or there is another way to generate the token to `https://chatsvcagg.teams.microsoft.com/api/v1/teams/users/me` url like Microsoft does?

Answer (score 0):

@Gaspar, multiple api calls can be batched using [json batching](http://@Gaspar,%20You%20have%20dependency%20of%20groupID%20to%20send%20next%20GET%20request%20for%20channel.%20You%20need%20to%20call%20api's%20one%20by%20one.%20%20For%20your%20second%20question%20-%20there%20is%20no%20one%20particular%20api%20which%20will%20get%20you%20all%20the%20information%20like) but any interdependent calls batch can not handle. 
If you have any dependency, you have to make separate calls.

Comment: In case it's not clear, this is because you need the IDs of the teams, which you get in the first call, for the {groupId}. What you could do is do 1 call to get the IDs, and then just one more batched call to get all the channels for all the groups, based on the ids you've just gotten.

Comment: Yeah that's right, batching is for _each individual request_, sow how we can do the same request as Microsoft Teams does? Bringin all information of the tenant? We just can not do it?

Comment: I am not the only one who wants it ([#4137](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4137))